# ReactJS - Proper way for using immutability-helper in reducer

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, immutability, immutability-helper

I have the following object which is my initial state in my reducer:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  campaign_dates: {
    dt_start: '',
    dt_end: '',
  },
  campaign_target: {
    target_number: '',
    gender: '',
    age_level: {
      age_start: '',
      age_end: '',
    },
    interest_area: [],
    geolocation: {},
  },
  campaign_products: {
    survey: {
      name: 'Survey',
      id_product: 1,
      quantity: 0,
      price: 125.0,
      surveys: {},
    },
    reward: {
      name: 'Reward',
      id_product: 2,
      quantity: 0,
      price: 125.0,
      rewards: {},
    },
  },
}
```

And my reducer is listening for an action to add a reward to my object of rewards:

```
    case ADD_REWARD:
      return {
        ...state, campaign_products: {
          ...state.campaign_products,
          reward: {
            ...state.campaign_products.reward,
            rewards: {
              ...state.campaign_products.reward.rewards,
              question: action.payload
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

So far so good (despite the fact that every object added is named "question")... its working but its quite messy. I've tried to replace the reducer above using the immutability-helper, to something like this but the newObh is being added to the root of my state

```
case ADD_REWARD:
   const newObj = update(state.campaign_products.reward.rewards, { $merge: action.payload });
   return { ...state, newObj }
```

Comment: https://immerjs.github.io/immer/docs/introduction
take a shot for immer.js, really cool tool for immutable reducers, simple to learn and execute

Comment: I have answered the problem below, but I agree with @OnerT.'s suggestion. From my experience, Immer is more intuitive as it allows you basic JS syntax instead of forcing you into special notation.

Comment: Thanks! I'll definitely going to check immer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return { ...state, newObj }
```

First, you must understand how the [object shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015) works. If you're familiar with the syntax before ES2015, the above code translates to:

```
return Object.assign({}, state, {
  newObj: newObj
});
```

Note how the `newObj` becomes a key and a value at the same time, which is probably not what you want.

I assume the mentioned `immutability-helper` is this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/immutability-helper. Given the documentation, it returns a copy of the state with updated property based on the second argument.

You're using it on a deep property so that it will return a new value for that deep property. Therefore you still have to merge it in the `state`, so you have to keep the approach you've labelled as messy.

What you want instead is something like:

```
const nextState = update(state, {
  $merge: {
    campaign_products: {
      reward: {
        rewards: action.payload
      }
    }
  }
});

return nextState;
```

Note how the first argument is the current `state` object, and `$merge` object is a whole object structure where you want to update the property. The return value of `update` is `state` with updated values based on the second argument, i.e. the next state.

Side note: Working with deep state structure is difficult, as you've discovered. I suggest you look into [normalizing the state shape](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape/). If applicable, you can also [split the reducers](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers/#splitting-reducers) into sub-trees which are responsible only for the part of the state, so the state updates are smaller.